# Как повторять таймер каждый час?

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем добрый. У меня есть код таймера. Мне нужна информация как сделать повторение таймера каждый час.
Повторять надо также согласно введёному числу (работать должно всё время работы программы)

Код таймера.`Dispatcher timer = new Dispatcher ();
Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Click);

```
        Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);

        Timer.Start();
```

`

```
private void Timer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DateTime d;

        d = DateTime.Now;

        if (d.Hour == hours && d.Second < 1)
        {
            if (d.Minute == minutes)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(eevent);
private static void eevent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    int dateTime = DateTime.Now.Hour;
    if(dateTime <= DateTime.Now.Hour || (dateTime == 23 && DateTime.Now.Hour == 0))
    {
       dateTime = DateTime.Now.Hour;
    }
}
```